# Restore remote Git branch

Tags: git, github

Before i go any further, let me explain why we can't do a:

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

Basically the branch (let's call it **dev1**) was on another developer's machine. He had done some commits and pushed them up. This branch was branched from another branch (we can call this **Features**) that was being renamed to **development**.
**development** was created as a branch of **Features** and then features was deleted.
The developer's branch (**dev1**) was then deleted by the other developer both locally and remotely. When using github for windows he found that all the branches we asking to be pushed, so he deleted the entire folder (which skipped the recycle bin) and re-cloned the repo.
So now he can't do a:

```
git reflog
```

because it doesn't have any history. I can't see his commits because they were never pulled locally onto my machine.

So, with that in mind, is there a way of restoring his **dev1** branch remotely? 
I have been looking for a command that would show all remote branches that were deleted, but thus far, have been unable to find such a command.

Any help will avoid weeks of development work!

Comment: Since dev1 had been pushed before it was deleted, dev1's tip commit and its parents are expected to exist in the remote repo, most probably as dangling objects. Make a new clone and run `git fsck` to find all the dangling objects and find commit objects among them. `git cat-file -t <object-sha1>` can list the object type. Run `git show` to check these dangling commits one by one. I think you can find out which commit is dev1's tip. If it's found, run `git branch dev1 <sha1>` to restore it and then push `dev1` back.

Comment: he did do a clone and when he does a `git fsck` he gets nothing returning at all

Comment: Two possibilities I could think of. One is dev1's tip is now still referenced by other branches or tags, maybe `development`. The other is the dangling objects are pruned by `git gc`. If the first, you could find it among `development`'s history. If the second, maybe only a file recovery tool can help.

Comment: But it looks like `development` was created locally and pushed remotely without pulling in the commits from `dev1`. Would a file recovery tool work when branches have been swapped, deleted, etc?

Comment: When a `branch` is deleted, just a ref is gone. The commits it once reached are still there before `git gc` wipes them out if they are unreachable from any branch, tag or reflog. If the repo is deleted without any backup, the commits (commit objects, tree objects, blob objects as files) are gone. Doing no backup is a big problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) to see the last 300 events (paginated in 30 events per page) occured during the last 90 days for a user or for a repo. There you can search for the last push event on that branch and thus get the SHA-1 that you need to reinstantiate as branch.

E. g. here you can see my recent events: https://api.github.com/users/Vampire/events, https://api.github.com/users/Vampire/events?page=2, a. s. o.

or here the events for the repository `vivin/gradle-semantic-build-versioning`: https://api.github.com/repos/vivin/gradle-semantic-build-versioning/events, https://api.github.com/repos/vivin/gradle-semantic-build-versioning/events?page=2, a. s. o.

Comment: sounds great, but the repo is private and without creating an application and using OAuth, doesn't appear I can see the events tied to the repo.

Comment: You can. Just use basic authentication (https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/). I just tried it and with basic auth I get info about my private gists, repos and so on, without I don't.